# Changing the call of Dll version in c#

Tags: c#

Is there any way to change the reference of a dll that is made automatically in c#?

That is, Actually this question is based on my own question that you can find here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271116/sqlserver-batchparser-issue-while-trying-to-execute-sql-scripts-using-c-sharp

In the exception which I recieve, I could find that C# is referring the sqlserver.batchparser.dll which is having the version "9.0.242.0". But when I check in my assembly (C:\Windows\Assembly) I could find the same file having version "10.0.0.0" for both x86 and 64 versions.

So, can I change the present way of calling this dll to make it call the same dll with new version?

Comment: if you want to check something in the assembly at runtime whether its version, members, properties, etc  you can try using .net reflection.

Comment: @Yoda: I dont want to check, because i am sure that it is calling lower version dll. How can I make c# call the new version of that file?

Comment: have you got the same namespace and class names in both the versions?

Comment: you can use external alias concept or dynamic if you are using c# 4.0 or as Marshall777 has answered use the right version that you want to use. The first two will make sense if you want to keep both the versions of dll.

Answer (score 2):

When you manage the dependencies of your project (using the solution explorer of VS) you can choose the right version of the assembly you want to use.

In your case, it looks like your assembly have been compiled with the 9.0.242.0 version of your dll and only the 10.0 version is present on the machine. So you can either change the assembly in your project dependencies to use the right (10.0) version or you can put the 9.0 version of the assembly causing the exception in the directory of your application.

Comment: In the solution explorer of Visual Studio, you'll find a "references" folder under your project name. In it, you should find the batchparser assembly. Remove it then do a right click on your project name then Add > reference and select the batchparser assembly matching the version you need

Comment: I have done like browsing and selecting the same dll from my assembly folder. inside this only I have this dll, but with version number 10.0.0.0

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal check my answer. at runtime compiler changes the version if it finds as the specific version property is set to false by default. To use the same , you need to set that property to true.

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal Have you tried putting the 10.0 dll in the directory containing the .exe file ?

Comment: @Marshall777:I cant copy that dll file since it is directly installed and can be found in c:\Windows\assembly

Comment: Check what is in the GAC (gacutil -l nameofassembly.dll) and look especially at the version. Btw I don't understand why the fact that the dll is present there prevents you from copying it ?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments above, [either reference right dll version in the project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx). If you want to use both, then either use external alias concept or use dynamic (c# 4.0).

You can also try setting the specific version property for a assembly you have reference to true. By default, it is set to false. Right click on a assembly under references and click properties. [image: find the attached image]
[Reference for external alias concept](http://mynameiskali.blogspot.co.uk/p/c-20-using-different-versions-of-same_24.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Assembly Binding Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx). Define these redirections in `web.config` or `app.config`.